# my result does not show the result in geometry image

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgadmin-4

my pgAdmin4 does not show me the output in image despite the postgis extension is enabled. Here is the result as a case.

`POLYGON((1.337060775394912 -1.111140466039209,1.152240934977428 -0.765366864730185,1.03842943919354 -0.390180644032262,1 -6.462170208665352e-15,1.038429439193538 0.39018064403225,1.152240934977424 0.765366864730173,1.337060775394905 1.111140466039198,1.5 1.309682485677078,1.662939224605084 1.111140466039215,1.847759065022569 0.765366864730191,1.961570560806458 0.39018064403227,2 0,1.961570560806461 -0.390180644032256,1.847759065022574 -0.765366864730179,1.662939224605091 -1.111140466039204,1.5 -1.309682485677078,1.337060775394912 -1.111140466039209))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your geometry stored in a `geometry` or `geography` type column? What you show in your question is a [WKT (Well Known Text) representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) of a polygon, not the polygon itself in the "PostgreSQL format". This is how your polygon should look like in order for you to plot it in the [Geometry Viewer](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/editgrid.html):

`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`

See it for yourself:

[image]

Note: For visuailisation purposes, I took the liberty of adding the reference system 4326 (WGS84). The casting from WKT to geometry is in the end of the statement as `::geometry`

`SELECT 'SRID=4326;POLYGON((1.337060775394912 -1.111140466039209,1.152240934977428 -0.765366864730185,1.03842943919354 -0.390180644032262,1 -6.462170208665352e-15,1.038429439193538 0.39018064403225,1.152240934977424 0.765366864730173,1.337060775394905 1.111140466039198,1.5 1.309682485677078,1.662939224605084 1.111140466039215,1.847759065022569 0.765366864730191,1.961570560806458 0.39018064403227,2 0,1.961570560806461 -0.390180644032256,1.847759065022574 -0.765366864730179,1.662939224605091 -1.111140466039204,1.5 -1.309682485677078,1.337060775394912 -1.111140466039209))'::geometry`